# Set data for all columns in table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `users` filled with columns. There's a column called `daily_points` that I want to change to 3 for every column in the table. How do I do this? Replace won't work, since it will affect data.

Comment: for every **row** you mean, right ?

Comment: Do you want to update column `daily_points` for each and every rows of table `users`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need an `UPDATE` query to set `daily_points = 3` for each and every rows of your `users` table so

```
UPDATE `users` 
SET `daily_points` = '3';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the value of the `column` `daily_points` to `3` for all `rows` within the table `users` then you can use the following statement.

```
UPDATE users SET daily_points = 3;
```